# Building a simple image recognition engine by tensorflow cifar10 example

Tags: python, image, classification, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to make a simple engine to classify image dataset and I am asking for guide or help.

I have already trained dataset and save the train model (1000000) and eval about 86.6%.

Then, Here is steps that I would like to follow:

1. Download image and convert into tensorflow dataset (I am not sure since it's all converted to bin type
2. Input image on trained model by cifar10 and test whether this image is dog, cat or sth else (print value would be... this image would be dog with 70% accuracy)
3. or distribute image folder if I input several images.

The whole purpose of this is to visualize all the process and use it in real by tensorflow.

I would appreciate if anyone could at least give me the ref.